# Как проверить статус удалённой машины (online/offline) с помощью python?

Tags: python, ip, requests

Нашел такое решение requests:

```
def status():   
 try:
    response = requests.get("http://myadress.com")
    response.raise_for_status()
 except HTTPError as http_err:
    return 1
 except Exception as err:
    return 1
 else:
    return 0
```

Прекрасно работает, но только с URL.
А вот так уже не работает, ничего не возвращает, скрипт просто висит:

```
def status():   
 try:
    response = requests.get("http://84.120.120.101:8181")
    response.raise_for_status()
 except HTTPError as http_err:
    return 1
 except Exception as err:
    return 1
 else:
    return 0
```

Мне не принципиально использовать этот код, просто нужно проверить статус удаленной машины.

P.S.
Вся проблема в пробросе порта, без проброса Все варианты работают!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import os

hostname = "10.10.10.11"
response = os.system("ping -n 1 " + hostname)

if response == 0:
    print(hostname, 'is up!')
else:
    print(hostname, 'is down!')
```

Если вы используете этот скрипт в unix / Linux, замените ключ -n на -c!

либо

```
import socket

def isOpen(ip,port):
   s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
   try:
      s.connect((ip, int(port)))
      s.shutdown(2)
      return True
   except:
      return False
```

Comment: Спосибо Вам огромное, второй вариант работает, задержка правда огромная  около 2 минут, но в моем случяе так даже лучше, будет ждать пока клиент не появится в сети. Вся проблема в пробросе  порта, без проброса Все варианты работают.

Comment: попробуйте уменьшить значение в s.shutdown() или заменить на s.close

Comment: Спасибо, время я стазу уменьшил, а s.close не помогло , доих пор весит :)

Comment: а если перед s.connect() Добавить s.settimeout() со значением, допустим 2?

Comment: Теперь OK, нужно поигратся  и так  и так попробую. клиент ооочень странный на базе ESP-8266. У меня эта проверка в цикле и в лог потом пишет "check status" так вот он иногда  5-6 раз подряд в лог выводит эту задпись, а если его физически отключить тогда ждет 2 мин.